# react-native-asset module not found

Tags: reactjs, react-native, node-modules

Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Users\satyen\Desktop\ExpoGame\react-native.config.js'
Require stack:

- C:\Users\satye\node_modules\react-native-asset\lib\cli.js

I'm trying to use custom fonts for react-native but I'm keep getting this error even though I made config file and globally installed react-native-assets still its not going.

Comment: don't mind the location. they are the same "satye" = "satyen". I just accidentally put n there.